# what's the best return type for Select LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm just getting started with LINQ and C# and I'm unsure what's the recommended return type for a LINQ statement that returns a bunch of records.

I found the following two notations that work both when linking the data to a gridview. Which approach should I use in what situation?

```
public object SelectAll()
    {
        var query = from p in dc.Products
                    select new { p.pk_product_id, p.product_name, p.product_price_kg };
        return query;
    }

public IQueryable<Product> SelectAll2()
{
    var query = from p in dc.Products
                select p;
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to return `object`. I wonder where you have seen this.
`IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` is the preferred way.

Comment: +1, but... `IQueryable<Product>` / `IEnumerable<Product>`, to be precise. `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` are different types.

Comment: @AakashM: Anonymously typed ViewModels? That sounds ... strange :-)

Comment: @AakashM: Saying "the client won't care about the return type" is no good reason for a method to return the wrong type.

Comment: Well, I think of ViewModel as a concept; for instance, I can't think of a better name for the things in the sequence returned by `SelectAll` in this question.

Comment: IQueryable is preferred over an IEnumerable
http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/12614

Comment: @Craig what's the 'right' type for `SelectAll` in this question? `IEnumerable<object>` is the most specific type I can think of that works; does specifying that really add anything?

Comment: I saw it in a text book about ASP.NET ... not a text-book example I assume :)

Comment: @AakashM, the "right type" is `IQueryable<Product>` or `IEnumerable<Product>`, just like @Daniel said. What it adds is compile-time type safety. You can now, e.g., write a unit test without casting the results. You'll also get a compiler error if you change the code to something which won't return the expected type.

Comment: Gridview reflects the bound properties, so binding an anonymous type (or object) would work. But agreed it is rather horrid.

Comment: @Craig would you say then to always create a *named* presentation type, where the view wants to present stuff not on the entity itself? (I've seen [this blog post of yours](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/) )

Comment: @Jorre the (current!) MSDN sample for `ObjectDataSource` still uses `ArrayList` and returns an `ICollection`, so... be careful what you trust :)

Comment: @AakashM Probably. You'd be unable to customize the GridView (e.g., with `DisplayNameAttribute` ) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If this method only gets called as the `SelectMethod` of a `GridView`, then *it doesn't matter*. The `GridView` code will be checking at execution time exactly what kind of data it's been given, and deciding what to do with it on the basis of what it is. Strong-typing the *method* doesn't make any difference to the `GridView`.

If you're going to be consuming this method from your own code, then use the most specific type that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building reusable data access code (and not just a query for a specific form or control) then you should take a look at repository patterns - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164342/should-repositories-implement-iqueryablet).

In this case you would want to return strongly typed entities from the query (and not objects from the result of an anonymous class)

PS : you can shorten SelectAll2 to

```
return dc.Products.AsQueryable();
```